# Sphinxsearch ignore_chars and exceptions work around

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I have an exceptions file which breaks the functionality of the ignore_chars directive.

The example keyword I am working with is `t-shirt`.

`t-shirt` appears in the database. I need the ignore_chars directive to ignore the `-` so users can search like `tshirt` or `t-shirt` and get the same results.

The result of `CALL KEYWORDS('tshirt t-shirt', 'catalog')` here is

```
+-----------+------------+
| tokenized | normalized |
+-----------+------------+
| tshirt    | TXRT       |
| tshirt    | TXRT       |
+-----------+------------+
```

To get `t shirt` to map to the above results, I have created an exceptions file which looks like this:

```
t shirt > tshirt
```

When I do the query `CALL KEYWORDS('t shirt tshirt t-shirt', 'catalog')` this is what I get:

```
+-----------+------------+
| tokenized | normalized |
+-----------+------------+
| tshirt    | TXRT       |
| tshirt    | TXRT       |
| shirt     | XRT        |
+-----------+------------+
```

What I expected to happen was the exceptions file would rewrite the 'words' `t shirt` to the individual keyword `tshirt` and all 3 tokens would have the same normalized value.

Except now the `-` in the `t-shirt` keyword isn't ignored and it just maps to `shirt`, which results in a completely different normalized version than `tshirt`. On top of this, searching with any of the related keywords above returns 0 results.

When I take out the exceptions file, the ignore_chars work fine and search works again for the keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I went down this path was because I couldn't get the wordform `t shirt > tshirt` to work.

Wordforms are applied after being tokenized and I thought this was the reason it did not work.

It turns out that my `min_word_len` was set to `3`, so the `t` in `t shirt` was not getting read properly. I reduced the `min_word_len` to `1` and now the wordform works properly.

This still does not solve the issue with `ignore_chars` and `exceptions`, but the search term works now, so I suppose this was the work around I needed.